# Is there any ways to open my web application in full screen in ASP.Net MVC without any user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is there any ways to open my web application in full screen (as like press F11) in ASP.Net MVC without any user interaction.

I am using below codes but this not working on page load time, this is working when user action in page.
But I need to open my web page in full screen when page is loaded.

Below code is working on click event but not working on page load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html:-moz-full-screen {
            background: red;
        }

        html:-webkit-full-screen {
            background: red;
        }

        html:-ms-fullscreen {
            background: red;
            width: 100%;
        }

        html:fullscreen {
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background:white;">
    <button id="btn">Fullscreen</button>
    <div id="test" style="width:512px; height:100px; background-color:#000000;" >
        <span>this is test</span>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('test');
            fullScreen(canvas);
        });

        function fullScreen(element) {
            if (element.requestFullScreen) {
                console.log("1");
                element.requestFullScreen();
            } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                console.log("2");
                element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                console.log("3");
                element.mozRequestFullScreen();

            }
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please suggest how can we done it?

Comment: Do you mean by browser fullscreen?

Comment: yes Hemal, I need my web page open in fullscreen mode

Comment: Try using `<body onload="fullScreen(document.documentElement)">` if you want to load current page in fullscreen mode by default.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto- Not working

Comment: @HarryDev: Seems that W3 spec preventing what you want: http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html. Since `onload` is an event triggered by page request (not by user request), it is no other way to override this behavior unless fullscreen event triggered by user interactions immediately after page is loaded.